# What is the pinout for HTC One X docks?

Tags: charger, mobile, pinout

I used to have a Motorola Milestone which used magnets to detect car and desktop docks.

I've now got an HTC One X and am looking for dock options. The standard ones look pretty expensive, but there are [some products](http://shop.htcpedia.com/htc-usb-cable-activates-car-dock-app.html?campaign_id=12) on the market which suggest it's probably just resistors between some of the lines like [the iPhone](http://www.ladyada.net/make/mintyboost/icharge.html)?

Does anyone know what the magical combination is for the desktop and car docks?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1654099) forum the pinout is as as follows:

> It's the micro USB pinout in pogo form..
>   1. 5vcc
>   2. Data -
>   3. Data +
>   4. Audio out mono
>   5. Ground. 
>   
>   Left to right pinout with the camera facing your left shoulder.

Regarding the car dock option I could not find any information.

Comment: It's the dock information I'm really after.